# Stored procedure vs simple SQL performance comparison

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

Performance comparison between a stored procedures and simple SQL queries in C# OR linq queries.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetProductCM] 
AS 
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON 

    SELECT 
        p.ProductId, 
        p.ProductName, 
        p.CategoryId
    FROM 
        dbo.Product p
END
```

```
using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(con))
{
    string oString = "SELECT p.ProductId, p.ProductName,  p.CategoryI FROM dbo.Product p";

    SqlCommand oCmd = new SqlCommand(oString, myConnection);
    myConnection.Open();

    using (SqlDataReader oReader = oCmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (oReader.Read())
        {    
            Product.ProductName= oReader["ProductName"].ToString();
            Product.CategoryI = oReader["CategoryI "].ToString();                       
        }

        myConnection.Close();
    }               
}
```

```
var queryAllProduct  = from p in Product 
                       select p;
```

What is the best practice?

Comment: My understanding is that execution plans get cached anyways nowadays. The only notable difference would probably be in the fact that you can limit the columns you pull with a stored procedure which would limit the data transfer size and the time spent on projections.

Comment: The reason to use Stored Procedures isn't query performance, it's security, security management and database administrative issues.  However, it also makes performance *management* easier, and can give *some* separation of client-code from database schema issues.

Comment: One bonus of SP's is that you can clear the plan cache per stored procedure when a bad stored procedure plan gets cached. For add-hoc queries, you have to clear all ad-hoc plans via DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE('SQL Plans')

Comment: As the current answer shows, this is more a topic for holy wars than anything else. You will find no shortage of people to advocate that either ad-hoc queries or stored procedures are the devil's tools and the other technology is clearly the superior being, due to <insert reasons here>. For performance, the question is actually even more complicated than you think, due to things like parameter sniffing, but the bottom line is that either approach can be made to perform as well as the other, albeit with different techniques. (I will say forcing plans for ad-hoc queries is no fun though.)

Comment: Note that whichever technology you use, make sure it's not susceptible to SQL injection -- in other words, if you use "simple queries" make sure to parameterize them, and not concatenate strings. Parameterization is possible regardless of how you offer the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To not use a stored procedure.

The performance benefit of precompiled stored procedures was eliminated with SQL Server 7 (yes, that is 7 - 25 years or so ago, IIRC). Since then plans are cached and reused for dynamic SQL. Now stored procedures make only sense if

- The SQL is VERY large and he result very slow (reducing network traffic) and the network is slow.
- You do complex processing that requires brutal data transfers otherwise.

In fact, in your particular case I would use an ORM and LINQ and not waste my time manually writing SQL code (that easily accounts for 40% of a programs code) that can instead be generated.

Comment: Well, I would say that "Now SP's make only sense *for performance reasons* if..."  There are other very good reasons to use stored procedures.

Comment: Like more maintenance? Yes, I agree. If you want to spend your time maintaining simple sp's like above then you have a point - good way to double the hours you spend oin a project and make sure you are inefficient in queries.

Comment: C'mon Tom, it might add to the maintenance but it's not going to inherently make SQL more inefficient.  And the reasons as I've listed above are security, security administration, performance administration, database administration and some (small) code/schema independence.  As you may recall, I do both client-side development and database development and administration.  I am aware of the increased effort, but as with many other things that take extra effort, IMHO it is worth it.  I have tried both extremes and most intermediate approaches and I'm convinced that an SP-API is the way to go.